# How to print the string of a JSON Object

Tags: android, json, string, toast

I am registering a user through laravel api. Response is coming in json object.
Now I want to print message string of this object in Toast instead of writing "Acount Successfully created". what should I do.

> JSON Object
>   {
>       "success": true,
>       "data": {
>           "token": "//removed",
>           "name": "Abdullah"
>       },
>       "message": "User register successfully."
>   }

Here is the onResponse Method

> OnResponse

```
 @Override
                        public void onResponse(JSONObject response) {
                            try {
                                if ( response.getBoolean("success")) {
                                    Log.i("response", response.toString());
                                    Toast.makeText(RegisterActivity.this, "Account Successfully Created", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                                    startActivity(new Intent(getApplicationContext(), MainActivity.class));
                                    finish();
                                } else {
                                    Log.e("Response", response.toString());
                                    Toast.makeText(RegisterActivity.this, "" + response, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                                }
                            } catch (JSONException e) {
                                e.printStackTrace();
                            }
                        }
                    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can access to the properties using the get(String) method and then use the asText(); to get the value of the property as String:

```
public void onResponse(JSONObject response) {
 try {
  if (response.getBoolean("success")) {
   Log.i("response", response.toString());
   Toast.makeText(RegisterActivity.this, response.get("message").toString(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
   startActivity(new Intent(getApplicationContext(), MainActivity.class));
   finish();
  } else {
   Log.e("Response", response.toString());
   Toast.makeText(RegisterActivity.this, "" + response, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
  }
 } catch (JSONException e) {
  e.printStackTrace();
 }
}
```